# dynamic data table-java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I work with a template that has the option of a data-table.
I am trying to generate the data-table rows dynamically using java script.
The table appears but the search is not working.
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Here you see the code:

```js
 function renderFeed(results) 
 {
    results = $.parseJSON(results.d);
    dynamicRow = "";
    dynamicModal = "";
    $.each(results, function (i, row) {

        dynamicRow += "<tr><td class='stars' data-name='star-outline' data-code='f27c'><a id='" + row.Id + "' onclick='changeToFavorit(this.id)'><i class='zmdi zmdi-star-outline zmdi-hc-fw'></i></a></td><td><a style='color: #2196f3' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal'" + row.Id + "'>" + row.Name + "</a></td><td>" + row.InstitutionName + "</td><td>" + row.Country + "</td><td>" + row.City + "</td><td>" + row.StartDate + "</td><td>" + row.Applicants + "</td><td><input type='file' name='uploadedfile' id='CVSfile" + row.Id + "' class='inputfile' /><label for='CVSfile" + row.Id + "'><i class='zmdi zmdi-upload zmdi-hc-fw'></i></label> <a id='deleteCourse" + row.Id + "' onclick='deleteCourse(this.id)'><i class='zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-fw'></i></a></td></tr>";
        dynamicModal += "<div tabindex='-1' class='modal fade' id='modal" + row.Id + "' aria-hidden='true' style='display: none;'><div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header'><h2>" + row.Name + "</h2></div><div class='modal-body'><h5>Number Of Course:</h5><p>" + row.Id + "</p><h5>Name Of Institution:</h5><p>" + row.InstitutionName + "</p><h5>Start Date:</h5><p>" + row.StartDate + "</p><h5>End Date:</h5><p>" + row.EndDate + "</p><h5>Descision Due Date:</h5><p>" + row.DesDate + "</p><h5>Description:</h5><p>" + row.DescC + "</p><h5>Requirement:</h5><h6>Education Degree:</h6><p>" + row.EducationType + "</p><h6>Languages:</h6>";

        $.each(row.Clan, function (i2, row2) {
            dynamicModal += "<p>" + row2.Name + "</p>";

        });

        dynamicModal += "<h6>Featured Skills & Endorsements:</h6>";

        $.each(row.TagsList, function (i3, row3) {
            dynamicModal += "<p>" + row3.Name + " - " + row3.Seniority;
            if (row3.Seniority == 1)
                dynamicModal += " year";
            else dynamicModal += " years";
            dynamicModal += "</p>";

        });

        dynamicModal += "</div><div class='modal-footer'><button class='btn btn-link' type='button' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button></div></div></div></div>";

    }
    );
    $('#tabelRows').empty();
    $('#tabelRows').append(dynamicRow);
    $('#modalsContent').empty();
    $('#modalsContent').append(dynamicModal);
    }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <table id="data-table" class="table table-bordered">
     <thead class="thead-default">
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <th>Course Name</th>
             <th>Institute</th>
             <th>Country</th>
             <th>City</th>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Numbers of Applicans</th>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
     </thead>
 
     <tbody id="tabelRows"></tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="modalsContent"></div>
 </body> 
<html>
```

Comment: You'll need to [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) the datatable again after dynamically modifying the rows.

Comment: @RRK Ok, can you help me how do I do this? 
when i tried to do    $('data - table').draw()   it was a mistake.

Comment: Does this `$('#data - table').draw()` make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initialize a table:

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-dark table-stripe " id="data-table-Editevent">
    <thead class="thead-light">
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th> Start Time</th>
          <th>Start Date</th>
          <th>End Date</th>
          <th> End Time</th>
          <th>Created By</th>
<!-- Add more columns based on your table structure -->
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<!-- Data will be populated dynamically here -->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

To append data to table from backend:

```js
function FilterEventsData() {  
   $.ajax({
       url: '/WebAI/ajax/SchedulesFunctions.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: {
          FUNCTION_NAME: "filterEvents",
          startDate: startDate,
          endDate: endDate,
          holidayName: holidayName
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (response) {
         // Clear the existing table rows
         $("#data-table-Editevent tbody").empty();
         // Populate the table with the updated data
         for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
         // Updated row append operation with proper closing tags
             $("#data-table-Editevent tbody").append("<tr data-id='" + response[i].idSchedule_Events + "'>" +
                        "<td>" + response[i].Event_Name + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + response[i].Start_Time + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + response[i].Start_Date + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + response[i].End_Date + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + response[i].End_Time + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + response[i].Created_By + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
          }
       },
       error: function (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching Data:", error);
       }
   });
}
```